# Setting up Cognito Auth with access key and secret access key in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am just beginning to learn rails, and am trying to configure AWS cognito authentication with my app.  My problem is that i am uncertain how to configure the correct `access_key` and `secret_access_key`.

I have configured cognito on node.js before, but it has only required a credentials related to the pool (i.e. client ID and User pool Id).  The ruby sdk that I am following here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html

wants my `access_key` and `secret_access_key`.

To generate these keys, I went into AWS IAM ->  Dashboard -> Delete your root access keys -> Manage Security Credentials

I then deleted all other security credentials that weren't working and generated a new pair.  Here is my code:

```
@cognito_client = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(
                    access_key_id: "GENERATED_ACCESS_KEY",
                    secret_access_key: "GENERATED_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
                    region: "us-east-1"
                  )

resp = @cognito_client.sign_up({
         client_id: "COGNITO_POOL_CLIENT_ID",
         username: email,
         password: password,
         user_attributes: [
           {
             name: "email",
             value: email
           },
           {
             name: "given_name",
             value: given_name
           },
           {
             name: "phone_number",
             value: phone_number
           }
         ]
       })
```

This is the error that I receive back in the console:

```
Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::NotAuthorizedException 
(Unable to verify secret hash for client COGNITO_POOL_CLIENT_ID):
```

Do I need to associate the cognito pool with the access_key_id and secret_access_key? If so, how do I do that?

Thank you for the help ahead of time.

Comment: Where are you declaring GENERATED_ACCESS_KEY and GENERATED_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need AWS credentials to make the sign-up call since it is an unauthenticated call from the point of view of AWS. The issue is that your user pool client has a client secret configured. There are 2 options here:

- use a user pool without a client secret. You can create one from the app clients tab and uncheck the Generate Client Secret box.
- pass the secret hash in your sign_up call. If your app has a way to secure client secrets, you can compute the secret hash from the client secret and pass it in your sign up call above. Here is a link to AWS documentation that explains how to compute the secret hash based on the client secret:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#cognito-user-pools-computing-secret-hash